# What are the types of NFTs smart contracts?

Tags: nft, smart-contract-wallets

I'm new in Web3 and I want to be specialized in NFTS I would like to know what are the types of NFTS smart contracts, I read that there are different types of courses based on each concept "Presale" Airdrop" "Marketplace". I just felt overwhelmed by all these types.

I would like to know what are all these types that exist in the market?

How can I understand deeply these concepts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way to answer this. There are standards as to what a "non fungible token" requires, such as the [ERC721 implementations](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC721) or ERC1155 implementations provided by OpenZeppelin. Other than that, every company has their own products that they have made to enhance or change the way that these NFTs interact.
As for the specific NFT attributes that you described, a presale NFT could refer to NFTs that can be purchased before minting. Airdrops refer to NFTs that can be given out in mass for free, or for no additional charge other than the gas that it requires to mint.
You can also try doing research on either Rarible or OpenSea to see how NFTs on those platforms are generated.